# If $f_x(x,t)$ is continuous in $t$, does this imply $f$ is continuous in $t$?

Tags: calculus, continuity

Let $f(x,t)$ be a function with $f_x \neq 0.$

If $f_x(x,t)$ is continuous in $t \in [0,T]$, does this imply $f$ is continuous in $t \in [0,T]$?

Comment: No, take a function $f$ that doesn't depend on $x$. Then $f_x \equiv 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer That is why I specified $f_x \neq 0$ :)

Comment: Well, just add a smooth function to the one that doesn't depend on $x$.

Comment: Whoops, sorry @DanielFischer!

Comment: @Sharkos What for? I see nothing you need to be sorry for here.

Comment: @DanielFischer Posted the same thing as an answer simultaneously is all, no biggy.

Comment: @Sharkos Not even a smallie ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose $$f(x,t) = g(x) + h(t)$$ with $g'\neq 0$ and $h$ discontinuous.

---

Perhaps a slightly more interesting question would be

> If $f(x,t)$ is continuous in $t$ over some range, and $\int_0^x f (x',t) \;\mathrm d x'$ exists, is the latter integral continuous in $t$?

I'll let you try that.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask then: under what conditions of $f_x$ does it hold that $f$ is continuous wrt. t?

Comment: @aere: There can be no such condition, since given any $f_x$ there is always some possible $f$ which is discontinuous in $t$ just by adding a suitably chosen $h(t)$.

Comment: Sorry, what about "under what conditions on $f$ (apart from cty. of $t$ itself). Eg. maybe if $f$ has a different form.

Comment: @aere Well there are various simple cases like $f(x,t)=g(x)h(t)$ with $g'\not\equiv 0$, but if you play with the question I gave you, perhaps you might start to see what is going on.